# How to fix cocoa pods flutter bug?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I am trying to run several dependencies on my flutter project however end up always getting the same error while running the project on ios and the full terminal message looks like this:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    Debug.xcconfig line 1: Unable to find included file "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
    Debug.xcconfig line 1: Unable to find included file "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/username/Desktop/flutter_test/xylophone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'assets_audio_player/AssetsAudioPlayerPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <assets_audio_player/AssetsAudioPlayerPlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
  brew install cocoapods
  pod setup

Xcode build done.                                            5.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Exited (sigterm)
```

This occurs with every dependency that I try to use from the flutter packages and I really don't know how to fix this. The process of installing cocoapods also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried 
`brew install cocoapods` and 
`pod setup` from your flutter project directory?

Comment: yep I have brew install cocoapods works, but pod setup doesn't it gives an error.

Comment: have you tried running `pod install` ?

Comment: yes it gives an error. The error is that there are no such files found in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

This has an existing [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293). [The error you've encountered](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293#issuecomment-738948703) was because the time you've installed cocoapods, it was installed with different version of ruby than you currently have active.

The recommended way to fix this is to to uninstall your existing cocoapods `brew uninstall cocoapods` and install a fresh one, via `sudo gem install cocoapods`.